# refactoring 2 similar if statement in ruby

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I am quite new in Ruby so would like to know and learn how to DRY. I have 2 if statement that's very similar, is there anyway to refactor it?

```
msg1,msg2 = msg.split('.')

if !msg1.nil?
   items = msg1.split(',')
   items.each do |item|
     item.strip!
   end
   somefunction(items)
end

if !msg2.nil?
   items = msg2.split(',')
   items.each do |item|
     item.strip!
   end
   somefunction(items)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can do away with the two variables:

```
msg.split('.').each do |msg|
 items = msg.split(',').map(&:strip)
 somefunction(items)
end
```

Edit: I removed the `unless` since the array created by `split` will not contain any. In your original code it made sense in case the array had 0 or 1 element, but by using `each` this becomes unnecessary.

Comment: Can you explain the map(&:strip)?

Comment: It's basically `map { |x| x.strip }`. `map` is similar to `each`, but collects all the results in an array (hence it's also aliased as `collect`). For understanding `&:` read up on the `Symbol#to_proc` method.

Answer (score 1):

We can write the same in a single line.

```
message.split('.').each{|msg| somefunction msg.split(',').collect(&:strip) }
```